# Partitions with number of rows oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a view in a Oracle DB, it looks as follows:

```
id  |  type  |   numrows 
----|--------|----------  
1   |   S    |      2     
2   |   L    |      3     
3   |   S    |      2     
4   |   S    |      2     
5   |   L    |      3     
6   |   S    |      2     
7   |   L    |      3     
8   |   S    |      2     
9   |   L    |      3     
10  |   L    |      3
```

The idea is: if TYPE is `'S'` then return 2 rows (randomly), and if TYPE is `'L'` then return 3 rows (randomly).
Example:

```
id  |  type  |   numrows
----|--------|----------  
1   |   S    |      2     
3   |   S    |      2     
2   |   L    |      3     
5   |   L    |      3     
7   |   L    |      3
```

Comment: Hi, Diego. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should tell oracle how to get 3 rows or 2 rows. An ideea is to fabricate a row:

```
select id, type, numrows
from
    (select 
       id, 
       type, 
       numrows, 
       row_number() over (partition by type order by type) rnk --fabricated
     from table)
where 
   (type = 'S' and rnk <= 2 )
   or
   (type = 'L' and rnk <= 3 );
```

You can order by anything you want in that analytic function. For example, you can order by `dbms_random.random()` for random choices.

If your column `numrows` is correct and that's the number of rows you want to get then the where clause is simpler:

```
select id, type, numrows
from
    (select 
       id, 
       type, 
       numrows, 
       row_number() over (partition by type order by dbms_random.random()) rnk --fabricated
     from table)
where 
   rnk <= numrows;
```